# .htaccess redirect all subdomains to single folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, directory

I have in a site with many user subdomains ie user1.example.com or user2.example.com.
I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

However this only works with same name folders. I want all subdomains to go to a single folder I have setup to parse the domain. How can I make all subdomains redirect to one folder?

Comment: You really don't need to use mod_rewrite to do this. You just setup the apache configuration to point all sub domains to the same directory.

Comment: Correct. You need to set the DocumentRoot directive in the Apache configuration (e.g. depending on your system and setup, it could be in htpd.conf, apache.conf, /etc/apache2/sites-anabled/your-site-name).

The directive looks something like this: 

`DocumentRoot /var/www/yoursitename`

Comment: Do you have access to Apache main configuration files, like httpd.conf and Vhost files?

Comment: I have access to everything, I set up the wildcard for subdomains. So would i add another virtualhost entry and add something like this  <VirtualHost IPAddress>
    ServerName *.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/public_html/sub
</VirtualHost>